# Azure Databricks Unity Catalogue Create metastore button unavailable

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

Trying to create a Metastore for manage identity incorporating in Azure Databricks but the data tab only shows create table.

Per the documentation, it should be there.  Also, I have created the databricks service and have azure contributor role.

I am an admin to the Databricks workspace. Is it unavailable on Azure?

[image]

Comment: could you please share your approach, how have you been created the metastore for manage identity? what is your metastore, storage account

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you don't give details about your environment, so I just can give some ideas about what is missing.

First, change the environment to "SQL" (click on "Data Science & Engineering" menu at the top left)

Second, do you have all the requirements? The requirements are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/get-started#requirements

I think do you missing this permission here:

*You must be an Azure Databricks account admin.

The first Azure Databricks account admin must be an Azure Active Directory Global Administrator at the time that they first log in to the Azure Databricks account console. Upon first login, that user becomes an Azure Databricks account admin and no longer needs the Azure Active Directory Global Administrator role to access the Azure Databricks account. The first account admin can assign users in the Azure Active Directory tenant as additional account admins (who can themselves assign more account admins). Additional account admins do not require specific roles in Azure Active Directory.*

To check if you are an Azure Databricks account admin you can access:

https://accounts.azuredatabricks.net/login?next_url=%2Flogin%2F

and verify if you have the access to the Databricks administration screen